# How to bind the JSON object data to knockout binding with template option?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I am working with knockout js. Now i am using template option and local json data as datasource.In this i am unable to bind the data to node within template.

Please get my html code below:

```
<div data-bind="template:{name:'treeTemplate',data:{da:Data}}"></div>
    <script id="treeTemplate" type="text/html">
       <b data-bind="text:$data.text"></b>
```

Please get my script section below

```
 var treeData = [
            { id: 1, text: "UK"},
            { id: 2, text: "Steven John" },
            { id: 3, text: "USA" },
            { id: 5,  text: "Andrew" },
            { id: 4, text: "Angelica" }
        ];


        window.viewModel = {
            value: ko.observable(new Date(2015, 06, 15)),
            Data:  ko.observableArray(treeData)
        };
        $(function () {
            // declaration
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
```

I have updated the sample in jsfiddle also. Please get the below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/38vnznht/

Can you please anyone suggest on this.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first problem is the use of data in the template object.

```
data:{da:Data}
```

for iterating through a array you need to use foreach

```
foreach:data
```

so because of this you need to update your bindings

```
// from this
<b data-bind="text:$data.text"></b>

// to this
<b data-bind="text: text"></b>
```

here is a working example : 
https://jsfiddle.net/wqe3s1vs/3/

Also, documentation on using "foreach" with a named template : 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-2-using-the-foreach-option-with-a-named-template

Comment: Thanks for suggestion now i understood